# Where am i going wrong for deleting a Node in a Binary Tree?

Tags: c++, oop, binary-tree, destructor, delete-operator

I am currently new to OOPS and was trying to write a class for basic Binary Tree implementation. When i try to delete a node, Inorder traversal doesn't work as it should.

Below is my current code. I have a few *couts* to LOG a few things as well.

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

    class Node {

public :
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;

public :
    Node(int x){
        data=x;
        left=right=NULL;
    }
    // ~Node(); 


    void inorder(Node *temp){
        if(!temp)
            return ;

        // cout<<"Sent :"<<temp->data<<"\n";

        inorder(temp->left);
        cout<<temp->data<<" "<<temp<<"\n";
        inorder(temp->right);
    }


    void insert(Node *temp,int x){

        queue<Node*> q;
        q.push(temp);

        while(!q.empty()){
            Node *t=q.front();
            q.pop();

            if(!t->left){
                t->left=new Node(x);
                break;
            }
            else
                q.push(t->left);

            if(!t->right){
                t->right=new Node(x);
                break;
            }
            else
                q.push(t->right);
        }
    }


    void deleteDepest(Node *temp, Node *delNode){

        queue<Node*> q;
        q.push(temp);

        while(!q.empty()){
            Node *t=q.front();
            q.pop();

            if(t==delNode){
                t=NULL;
                delete(delNode);
                return;
            }

            if(t->left){
                if(t->left==delNode){
                    t->left=NULL;
                    delete(delNode);
                    return;
                }
                else
                q.push(t->left);
            }
            
            if(t->right){
                if(t->right==delNode){
                    t->left=NULL;
                    delete(delNode);
                    return;
                }
                else
                q.push(t->right);
            }
        }
    }


    Node* deletion(Node *temp, int x){

        if(temp==NULL)
            return NULL;

        if(!temp->left && !temp->right){
            if(temp->data==x)
                return NULL;
            return temp;
        }

        queue<Node*> q;
        q.push(temp);
        Node *tt=NULL, *t;

        while(!q.empty()){
            t= q.front();
            q.pop();

            if(t->data==x){
                tt=t;
                // break;
            }

            if(t->left)
                q.push(t->left);
            if(t->right)
                q.push(t->right);
        }

        if(tt){
            cout<<"\ndelNode "<<tt->data<<" depest "<<t->data<<"\n";
            tt->data=t->data;
            deleteDepest(temp,t);
        }

        return temp;
    }
  };


   int main()
  {

Node *root = new Node(1);

root->left = new Node(2);
root->right = new Node(3);

// cout<<"Before insertion\n";
// root->inorder(root);

root->insert(root,4);
root->insert(root,5);

// cout<<"\nAfter insertion\n";
// root->inorder(root);

int d;
cout<<"\nEnter nod to delete :";
cin>>d;
root=root->deletion(root,d);
cout<<"\nAfter deletion\n";
cout<<"root :"<<root<<" "<<root->left<<"\n";
root->inorder(root);

cout<<"Ain't working";
cout<<root;

if(root->left->left)
    cout<<"\nroot->left->left :"<<root->left->left;
else
    cout<<"NULL\n";

return 0;
}
```

Even when i uncomment ~Node() it shows a error : **undefined reference to `Node::~Node()'**
**And even while running the code you can see *Ain't working* print statement isn't even being executed.**

Comment: Whichever C++ textbook instructed you to write `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in your code, you should throw it away and get yourself a better textbook. P.S. insertion and deletion logic appears to be quite broken. As it is, it seems to always insert on the left side of the node if it is initially `NULL`. That's what the logic shows. But what if the value to be inserted is greater than the node's value, but the `left` pointer is null, and the value needs to be inserted on the right side. How's that supposed to work? And why does insertion need a queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(t->right==delNode){
  t->left=NULL;
  delete(delNode);
```

You locate the node to be deleted on the `right`, but set the `left` pointer to `NULL`.